# Wget - Retrieving Recursive URLs from list of URLs

Tags: wget, url

I have a list of urls in a txt file. Each of these urls point to a page with another list of urls. What WGET command can I use to retrieve the urls from the pages that have been linked from the the urls in my txt file?

NOTE: I don't want to download files, but just output the list of urls to a txt file.

Answer (score 1):

(untested):

```
wget -r -l 1 -i file
```

`wget`command has many options... In this case:

- `-r` stands for recursive
- `-l 1` means just one level of recursion (try 2 if one was not enough)
- `-i file` means that file contains a list of staring point urls

Comment: Potential for +1 if you explain what that does

Comment: @roaima, yes: this needs an explanation...

Comment: @JJoao This downloads files that have been linked from the txt file. I just want a list of the names of the urls to be output to another txt file.